# environment with multiple python interpreter

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, anaconda

On Mac, if installed multiple Python interpreter (anaconda, Python 2.7 standard, etc.), wondering when running command `python`, is there a way to specify if I run with anaconda or Python 2.7 or other Python interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only type python, it will take you to the version of python specified by this:

```
which python
```

This command will print out the location of `python` in your terminal.

To use a version other than the one above, be it Jython or Anaconda or whatever, you can to run it by typing out the fully qualified path.

Comment: If you'd add consideration of environment variables like `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONLIB`, then this would become a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks touch my body, vote up. And wondering if I use full qualified path, for libraries using pip to install, will them be only usable under the specific python interpreter, or be used globally across all python interpreters? For example, if I install numpy using pip under normal python interpreter, but not under anaconda, then if I use full qualified path of anaconda to execute python interpreter, numpy cannot be used?

Comment: Thanks @SuperSaiyan, vote up for your idea and if you could comment on my above on 3rd party library install/use across different python interpreter, it will be great. :)

Comment: @LinMa: **Avoid what you are doing**. Google for `virtualenv`. That allows you to cleanly isolate multiple environments, separate interpreters, separate libraries.

Comment: Change your environment variable `PATH` such that whatever version you want to be default appears first in the list.